# Output from SIG handler in a detached daemon

Tags: php, stdout, daemon

I've written a daemon in PHP, which I launch from a terminal. The daemon has a couple of signal handlers (using pcntl_signal()), one of which outputs a few status messages using echo(). This is all fine and dandy, and works OK...

... until. If I disconnect my terminal and then reconnect, it doesn't matter what SIG I pass it, I get no output. I understand why - it's because the STDOUT that my daemon was attached to has gone away (my previous terminal session). However, I still want the signal handler to work, or it'll be pretty useless!

I have tried the following:

```
$fh = fopen("php://stdout","w");
fwrite($fh, "Here is a status message");
```

... however, this doesn't work, because it doesn't re-attach a new STDOUT, it tries to use the old one.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to figure out the tty of the current user and write directly to that. `/dev/console/` I would guess.